# Loading image captioning (Transformer) model

Tags: nlp, transformer-model

Hi guys i am using an image captioning model  with transformer and I am having trouble loading the weights of the model in TensorFlow with the commande : `model.load_weights('/image_captioning_weights.h5')`.
I got this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.
```

Here is how i implemented the model and train it and then saved the weights:

```
MAX_LENGTH = 40
VOCABULARY_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 512
UNITS = 512

image_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.3),
    ]
)

def CNN_Encoder():
    inception_v3 = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet'
    )
    inception_v3.trainable = False

    output = inception_v3.output
    output = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(
        (-1, output.shape[-1]))(output)

    cnn_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inception_v3.input, output)
    return cnn_model

class TransformerEncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_norm_1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layer_norm_2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.attention = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim, activation="relu")
    

    def call(self, x, training):
        x = self.layer_norm_1(x)
        x = self.dense(x)

        attn_output = self.attention(
            query=x,
            value=x,
            key=x,
            attention_mask=None,
            training=training
        )

        x = self.layer_norm_2(x + attn_output)
        return x

class Embeddings(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_dim, max_len):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            vocab_size, embed_dim)
        self.position_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            max_len, embed_dim, input_shape=(None, max_len))
    

    def call(self, input_ids):
        length = tf.shape(input_ids)[-1]
        position_ids = tf.range(start=0, limit=length, delta=1)
        position_ids = tf.expand_dims(position_ids, axis=0)

        token_embeddings = self.token_embeddings(input_ids)
        position_embeddings = self.position_embeddings(position_ids)

        return token_embeddings + position_embeddings

class TransformerDecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, embed_dim, units, num_heads):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = Embeddings(
            tokenizer.vocabulary_size(), embed_dim, MAX_LENGTH)

        self.attention_1 = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, dropout=0.1
        )
        self.attention_2 = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, dropout=0.1
        )

        self.layernorm_1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()

        self.ffn_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation="relu")
        self.ffn_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim)

        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(tokenizer.vocabulary_size(), activation="softmax")

        self.dropout_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)
        self.dropout_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
    

    def call(self, input_ids, encoder_output, training, mask=None):
        embeddings = self.embedding(input_ids)

        combined_mask = None
        padding_mask = None
        
        if mask is not None:
            causal_mask = self.get_causal_attention_mask(embeddings)
            padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, :, tf.newaxis], dtype=tf.int32)
            combined_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, :], dtype=tf.int32)
            combined_mask = tf.minimum(combined_mask, causal_mask)

        attn_output_1 = self.attention_1(
            query=embeddings,
            value=embeddings,
            key=embeddings,
            attention_mask=combined_mask,
            training=training
        )

        out_1 = self.layernorm_1(embeddings + attn_output_1)

        attn_output_2 = self.attention_2(
            query=out_1,
            value=encoder_output,
            key=encoder_output,
            attention_mask=padding_mask,
            training=training
        )

        out_2 = self.layernorm_2(out_1 + attn_output_2)

        ffn_out = self.ffn_layer_1(out_2)
        ffn_out = self.dropout_1(ffn_out, training=training)
        ffn_out = self.ffn_layer_2(ffn_out)

        ffn_out = self.layernorm_3(ffn_out + out_2)
        ffn_out = self.dropout_2(ffn_out, training=training)
        preds = self.out(ffn_out)
        return preds


    def get_causal_attention_mask(self, inputs):
        input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        batch_size, sequence_length = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
        i = tf.range(sequence_length)[:, tf.newaxis]
        j = tf.range(sequence_length)
        mask = tf.cast(i >= j, dtype="int32")
        mask = tf.reshape(mask, (1, input_shape[1], input_shape[1]))
        mult = tf.concat(
            [tf.expand_dims(batch_size, -1), tf.constant([1, 1], dtype=tf.int32)],
            axis=0
        )
        return tf.tile(mask, mult)

class ImageCaptioningModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, cnn_model, encoder, decoder, image_aug=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.cnn_model = cnn_model
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.image_aug = image_aug
        self.loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
        self.acc_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="accuracy")

    def calculate_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, mask):
        loss = self.loss(y_true, y_pred)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss.dtype)
        loss *= mask
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)


    def calculate_accuracy(self, y_true, y_pred, mask):
        accuracy = tf.equal(y_true, tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=2))
        accuracy = tf.math.logical_and(mask, accuracy)
        accuracy = tf.cast(accuracy, dtype=tf.float32)
        mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_sum(accuracy) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)
    

    def compute_loss_and_acc(self, img_embed, captions, training=True):
        encoder_output = self.encoder(img_embed, training=True)
        y_input = captions[:, :-1]
        y_true = captions[:, 1:]
        mask = (y_true != 0)
        y_pred = self.decoder(
            y_input, encoder_output, training=True, mask=mask
        )
        loss = self.calculate_loss(y_true, y_pred, mask)
        acc = self.calculate_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, mask)
        return loss, acc

    
    def train_step(self, batch):
        imgs, captions = batch

        if self.image_aug:
            imgs = self.image_aug(imgs)
        
        img_embed = self.cnn_model(imgs)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss, acc = self.compute_loss_and_acc(
                img_embed, captions
            )
    
        train_vars = (
            self.encoder.trainable_variables + self.decoder.trainable_variables
        )
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, train_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, train_vars))
        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.acc_tracker.update_state(acc)

        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result(), "acc": self.acc_tracker.result()}
    

    def test_step(self, batch):
        imgs, captions = batch

        img_embed = self.cnn_model(imgs)

        loss, acc = self.compute_loss_and_acc(
            img_embed, captions, training=False
        )

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.acc_tracker.update_state(acc)

        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result(), "acc": self.acc_tracker.result()}

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.loss_tracker, self.acc_tracker]

encoder = TransformerEncoderLayer(EMBEDDING_DIM, 1)
decoder = TransformerDecoderLayer(EMBEDDING_DIM, UNITS, 8)

cnn_model = CNN_Encoder()
caption_model = ImageCaptioningModel(
    cnn_model=cnn_model, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, image_aug=image_augmentation,
)

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False, reduction="none"
)

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)

caption_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=cross_entropy
)

history = caption_model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=val_dataset
)

caption_model.save_weights('imagee_captioning_weights.h5')
```

After i saved the model weights i created a instance of the model and tried to load the model where i got this error:

```
model = ImageCaptioningModel(
    cnn_model=cnn_model, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, image_aug=image_augmentation,
)
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=cross_entropy
)
model.load_weights('/imagee_captioning_weights.h5')
```

the output:

`ValueError: Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.`

Answer (score 0):

You should first train your model so your model achieve weights by the process of training; then saving them into a file and loading them after that. By your code provided and the error message, it implies that you have not already run your model and thus not learned any weights, and as a result, there is no any weight to save. check that and tell if it helps.